# "tar ./files.tar -C $HOME" results in a "tar: invalid option -- ." error

Tags: tar

I'm trying to run a tar command and I keep getting this odd error.

The command:

```
  tar ./files.tar -C $HOME
```

And I get this in return:

```
 Error: tar: invalid option -- '.'
```

My files.tar folder is located correctly near my script and contains some directories.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the options before the file name and so:

```
tar -xf files.tar -C $HOME
```

Comment: This just returns another error: tar: "C: Cannot open: No such file or directory"

Comment: Are you trying to extract the tar file files.tar?

Comment: The order of `x` and `f` must match the order of the arguments they are referring to. So `tar xfC files.tar $HOME`.

Comment: Yes I am. But extract them in the home directory.

Comment: @JohanMyréen That worked!